# How to check if esp now slave lost connection?

Tags: esp32

I want to send data from master to slave esp32 using esp_now protocol. The thing is, I want a separate function to run when esp-now master is on and connected, and when the master is switched off, it should run a different code.

Answer (score 1):

esp_now is connectionless.  There is no connection, so there's no way to know if a connection has been lost.  You just have to send the message, and use the  callback to tell if the message was received.  You can't detect that a priori.

You have the user's guide?  https://www.espressif.com/en/products/software/esp-now/resources

Answer (score 0):

Send a  variable that is not used by your program
for example you want to send characters from the
sender to receiver and let us say you are not using
char 'z' in your program, then in the sender program
loop keep sending 'z" every iteration,
now in receiver program loop keep checking for
char 'z', so as long as you receive char 'z', then
sender is alive and if you don't receive char 'z'
then sender is off or not connected.